# I have proper edge coloring of k-regular graph with k colors, I have one extra color to break all 2-colored cycles to get acyclic edge coloring.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a $k$-regular graph.

**Proper edge coloring** of a graph is assigning each edge a different color than its neighbors.

**Acyclic edge coloring** of a graph is proper edge coloring with extra condition that, the graph doesn't contain a 2-colored cycle, i.e. a cycle in which each alternate edge is colored with the same color.

Proper edge coloring of $G$ would be done by finding $k$ perfect matchings and edges in the same perfect matching will get the same color, thus a total $k$ color would be required here. This proper edge coloring will have one or more Hamiltonian cycle/s for each pair of colors. Hence the edge coloring is proper but not acyclic.

I have $(k+1)^{th}$ color to assign to the selective edges in such a way that it would break all Hamiltonian cycles of each pair of colors from $1 $ to $k$, and also $(k+1)^{th}$ color would not create cycle in $G$.

I have been struggling with this for a while, if anyone got any suggestion or idea please help with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more precise as to what you're struggling with. If nothing else, write down the relevant definitions in the body of your question and try to make some connections which can help potential "answerers" identify how best to help you.

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time, thank you for your suggestion, I have done some changes, please have a look.

Comment: For a fixed pair of colors, the corresponding cycles are not necessarily [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path). On the other hand, they are vertex-disjoint.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, yes you are right, I have not mentioned in that way. But the goal is to convert it into acyclic.